# WebScraping Dyanmic queryparameter unable to scrape a json response

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like your help with one of the web scraping methods. I have been trying to scrape in python using the requests module as a practice but am unable to do so. It has a JSON pagination and query parameter keeps on changing inside request headers. Due to this i am unable to handle it dynamically here is the link https://www.arp.fr/produits-portables-tablettes-ordinateurs-portables/?queryString=JTdCJTIyYXJlYUlkJTIyJTNBJTIyMkVEODhGMjctOTNFOS00NzQzLUI3NDYtRUNFQUJENUZFRDA4JTIyJTJDJTIyaXNRdWVyeSUyMiUzQWZhbHNlJTJDJTIyc29ydEF0dHJpYnV0ZSUyMiUzQW51bGwlMkMlMjJzb3J0RGlyZWN0aW9uJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMnBhZ2VubyUyMiUzQSUyMjElMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJQYWdlJTIyJTNBJTIyMTIlMjIlMkMlMjJ2YWx1ZXMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJwcm9kdWN0SWRzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIycGFydG5lcklkJTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMm9wdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUJudWxsJTJDbnVsbCUyQ251bGwlNUQlN0Q=&page=1&productfilter=&sort=null

It would be really helpful if someone would show on how to handle such websites with pagination ?
My goal is to scrape Product_Name, ProductUrl, and ProductDescription.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can work with, There is some stuff missing. But maybe it will be helpful

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def req(page):
    return requests.get(
    url = 'https://www.arp.fr/produits-portables-tablettes-ordinateurs-portables',
    params = {
        'page':page,
    })


def get_data(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    soup = soup.find('script', {'type':'application/json'})
    data = str(soup.contents)
    data = data.replace(' ', '').replace(r'\n', '').replace(r'\t', '').replace("'", '')
    return json.loads(data)[0]['ecommerce']['impressions']


def get_all_pages(page=1):
    r = req(page)
    if r.ok:
        yield get_data(r.content)
        yield from get_all_pages(page+1)

for x in get_all_pages():
    print(x)
```